# How to remember multiple tabs' session in terminal? (Alike FF session manager)

Tags: linux, tabs, undo, gnome-terminal

how does one "***undo close-tab***" in terminal? And quite related to it, is it possible to **remember a session of tabs in terminal**?

I mean (alike Firefox) if I close all tabs in a particular terminal window, how do I open with same the next day?

Its really useful to remember the terminal session for people like me who use multiple tabs a lot, and do not wish to start the next day with remembering what (and whereall) one was working, when one left the desk the day before.

In mouse right-click menu of gnome-terminal, one could easily (and I *have*) mistakenly click close tab instead of '*Copy*'and lost track of what and where one was before selecting the text selected. In this case, *undo closed-tab* will serve a great purpose (available in Firefox already)

Thanks!

--V

Answer (score 7):

For the gnome terminal, you can use

```
gnome-terminal --profile=〈your profile〉 --save-config=〈file〉
```

I launch it as a background task to save the terminal state periodically.

Comment: Hi! 
 I tried this, and got the following error! Any comments?

 `gnome-terminal --profile=Default  --save- config=~/.terminal.save.test

Failed to forward arguments: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code4: Failed to create file '/work/bkp.aka/organic/~/.terminal.save.test.S9BJXW': No such file or directory`

Comment: @kvaibhav - just tested on Ubuntu 11.04, GNOME Terminal 2.32.1, and the problem is use of tilde `~` in the arguments; note that it expands both to your home dir _and_ an extra tilde in `/work/bkp.aka/organic/~/...`. I got the same error when I used the tilde, but using a full path instead: `gnome-terminal --profile=mini --save-config=/home/username/.terminal.save.test` worked fine for me, and config file gets saved. Also, `--profile` in this version is not listed in `--help`, but it works (when starting, not for saving config). Hope this helps - cheers!

Comment: For gnome-terminal 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, `--profile` has no affect, that is `--save-config` works as though `--profile` was not given..

Answer (score 6):

"termit" can save sessions and is scriptable in lua: https://github.com/nonstop/termit/wiki
I don't know about an "undo close tab" feature, though.

For reference, my termit lua config can be found here: https://github.com/thet/dotfiles-termit

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, `gnome-terminal` is able to load multiple tabs with different working directories. Like termit (which is much more flexible due to it's lua scripting interface), it doesn't have a "undo close tab" feature.

Open Gnome terminal with multiple tabs, each one in another working directory: `gnome-terminal --tab --working-directory=/home --tab --working-directory=~ --tab --working-directory=/opt`.

Open Gnome terminal with multiple tabs and one base working directory: `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home --tab --tab --tab`.

For more options do: `gnome-terminal --help-all`.

Answer (score 3):

The gnome terminal doesn't have such features, but if you're open to change you could try [konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/), it has some nice 'save session' options you could find helpful, though nothing about re-opening accidentally closed tabs, as far as I know.

The other thing, if you're particular about your desktop, is that KDE's konsole might not fit all too well within Gnome.

Comment: Konsole dropped the 'save session' feature in recent versions. What you now have is the command option **--tabs-from-file**. It allows you to define multiple tabs with specific title, workdir, command and shell profile in a file. Check the [Command-line Options](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html) sections of the Konsole docs for an example and specs.