# xterm save terminal session and tabs

Tags: session, terminal, session-state

Is there a way or tool to save state of all tabs and session for `xterm`.

For example I have opened terminal with multiple tabs, each of tab has running command

[image]

I want to save *whole* terminal session, so I can reboot my PC and type one command eg

```
$ load_session last_session_file
```

and I will have the same tabs reopened, with the same commands, with the same *tabs title*.

PS I am using `Xubuntu 13.10` and `xterm`

```
@maci ➜  survey_manager rvm:(ruby-2.0.0) git:(fix-rake-db-seed) ✗ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

Comment: The picture is not of [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html).

Answer (score 2):

That looks like one of the miscellaneous wrappers for the VTE library.  The question has been asked before:

- [Save and restore session of the Gnome Terminal](http://aetas.pl/?p=196)

  > INFO: Unfortunately “–save-config” option is no longer supported in the new versions of gnome-terminal so this script will not work.
- [gnome-session-save not present, how to save sessions](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/38857/gnome-session-save-not-present-how-to-save-sessions/)
- [GNOME session saving dropped in natty](https://web.archive.org/web/20111106052911/http://www.linux-archive.org/ubuntu-desktop/478109-gnome-session-saving-dropped-natty.html)
- [How to remember multiple tabs' session in terminal? (Alike FF session manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048474/how-to-remember-multiple-tabs-session-in-terminal-alike-ff-session-manager)
- [Some fast way to save and restore tabs of Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310705/some-fast-way-to-save-and-restore-tabs-of-terminal)
- [GNOME 2.24 Session Save & Restore](https://blogs.oracle.com/mattman/entry/gnome_2_24_session_save1)

In a quick summary, it appears that session-saving/restoring fell into disfavor a few years ago because it was too difficult to do well.